# Excluding Environment Files from Github Angular 4 Project

Tags: git, angular, github, angular-cli

How do i exclude environment files from github for angular 4 project.

I have updated my .gitignore to the following, but my environment files are still being synchronised to github: /src/environments/**

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist
/tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
/node_modules

# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
.settings/
*.sublime-workspace

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings
/src/environments/**

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

# System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```

Comment: If any file once been tracked in git, this will always be tracked even it is mentioned in git-ignore. To remove the file cut and paste somewhere else, git commit and then move it back.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[To quote the Git website:](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_notes)

> The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.

In other words, gitignore won't remove files that are already in your repository, it'll just stop them being added in the first place. So if you've already accidentally commited your environment files, adding them to gitignore isn't enough; you'll also need to untrack the files.

The documentation goes on to say how to fix it:

> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.

Note that this won't remove the file from your commit history, however - if you've accidentally leaked any sensitive info, [see the GitHub documentation for info on what to do](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/).

Comment: Thank you - worked perfectly.  And i learnt something else about git.

Comment: @ccocker: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Full code for those who might be searching `git rm --cached -- ./src/environments/`

Comment: Or rather `git rm -r --cached -- ./src/environments/`